# Laptop restarts sometimes when I move the lid

Tags: restart

I have a 2006 Acer Aspire 5630 running Ubuntu 11.04. recently it started to have these symptoms:

1. Random restarts
2. Restarts whenever I move the lid forward or backward by one inch.
3. Restarts the most when I perform a cold power on
4. Sometimes it runs fine, when I move the lid the same way, nothing happens.

A one point I had this message after a boot.

[image]

What does that mean and why the lid is so sensitive? I'll be happy to hear what can I do.

Comment: I dont think this is the lid, but rather a wire from the lid is pulling out other wires or something.  I'd have it checked by a technician or the manufacturer if you can, as I think its a hardware issue.

Comment: "media test failure, check cable" to me is the most sensible answer: the hardware inside is faulty. When moving the lid it causes a power shortout causing it to reboot/crash. Find someone or a company that can safely open it and have a look inside. Oh and  PXE errors are generated by the network boot ROM. In other words, the boot process is attempting a network boot (your BIOS' 4th boot option), which means that your system was unable to boot from a HDD, CD-ROM, or USB device (the first 3 boot options).

Comment: thanhs  a lot. i did not know what it meant. could the hard disk be faulty also? i forgot to say that when booting in ubuntu there is a list that comes, with [ok] on the side.. and there is one [fail].. i cant see it because it is fast. and sometime a message saying  "power tx -5 fail"... if that changes a thing or give you a hint.. thanks again

Comment: No, I do not think so. I think that would result in other type of errors (more focused on `files not found`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure: please check your BIOS and confirm you did not put 'boot from LAN' as the 1st boot option. I assume it is not since moving the lid crashes your system.

PXE errors are generated by the network boot ROM: the boot process is attempting a network boot (probably your BIOS' 4th boot option), which means that your system was unable to boot from a HDD, CD-ROM, or USB device (the 'standard' first 3 boot options).

The error you posted "media test failure, check cable" to me holds the most sensible answer: the hardware inside is faulty. When moving the lid it causes a power shortout causing it to reboot/crash. Find someone or a company that can safely open it and have a look inside.

I do not believe it to be a HDD failure that would result in other type of errors more focused on `files not found`. You can some what try to confirm this by inserting a bootable cd and start from it. Move the lid and if it crashes you can comfirm it to be more likely to be hardware related.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i did try to boot a ubuntu 10.10 live cd, and when i moved the lid it did restart. i will send the laptop to a technician . i'll mark it as solved.